# Discord.py: How can I make a queue for a discord music bot?

Tags: python, discord, queue, bots, audio-player

I want to extend my play method so I can queue multiple songs. I tried to create a list and append songs everytime play is used, but I don't know how to start playing a song once a song has finished playing. The while-loop didn't work(I'm not sure but I think its because it doesn't use the updated versions of the list). My code is the following:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import re


class music(commands.Cog):

    song_queue = []
    vc = None

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    def skip(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.stop()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        # ctx.voice_client.stop()
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            await voice_channel.connect()
            await ctx.send("joined")
        self.vc = ctx.voice_client
        if self.vc.is_playing():
            await ctx.send("is playing")
            self.song_queue.append(url)
            s = "in queue " + str(self.song_queue)
            await ctx.send(s)
        else:
            self.song_queue.append(url)
            s = "in queue " + str(self.song_queue)
            await ctx.send(s)

            while len(self.song_queue) > 0:
                # neu
                url = self.song_queue[0]
                ex = "t=[0-9]+"
                groups = re.search(ex, url)
                link_no_playlist = re.split("&list", url)[0]
                if link_no_playlist is not None:
                    url = link_no_playlist
                if groups is None:
                    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5",
                                      "options": "-vn"}
                else:
                    timestamp = groups.group(0)[2:]
                    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5",
                                      "options": "-vn -ss "}
                    FFMPEG_OPTIONS["options"] = FFMPEG_OPTIONS["options"] + timestamp

                if ".com" not in url:
                    YDL_OPTIONS = {"verbose": True, "nocheckcertificate": True, "format": "bestaudio", "default_search": "auto",
                                   "noplaylist": True}
                else:
                    YDL_OPTIONS = {"verbose": True, "nocheckcertificate": True, "format": "bestaudio"}

                vc = ctx.voice_client

                with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)

                    if 'entries' in info:
                            video_format = info['entries'][0]["formats"][0]
                    elif 'formats' in info:
                        video_format = info["formats"][0]
                    # url2 = info["formats"][0]["url"]
                    url2 = video_format["url"]
                    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
                    vc.play(source)
                    await ctx.send("playing " + str(self.song_queue[0]))
                del self.song_queue[0]

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Btw I also get the error: "TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression", when I try to skip a playing song, which was fine before I changed the play method. Maybe this was caused by my main problem. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to activate this, you need to use a different thread so your bot won't stuck with other codes you have ( such as accepting more commands and things like that )
It's very simple actually, inside Your client there's something called client.loop.create_task(task_method())
This lets you loop from a different thread ( meaning the bot will still respond to your commands )

```
self.client.loop.create_task(self.create_loop_task())
```

This lets you go down to method 'create_loop_task' which in there there's a while where all song calculations are going to ( essentially where the bot starts playing music )

NOTE: As far as I'm aware there are two methods to do it, one is easier ( using lists as you did ) and one which might be more efficient ( using Nodes ), I'll put an explanation to both ways in case anyone needs it.

### **Method 1**

The first method I've worked with music bots is using lists, the good thing about using lists is the functions, it has far more functions to work with like randomizing and even shuffling, however, there is one critical issue and it's the lack of being able to grab your data easily, like the song or whatever, also.
What you do essentially is define a list inside the class and in this class, you'll add Songs, delete songs, shuffle them or whatever. In the list, it's a more pleasant way and less complicated than method 2.

Code snippet from what I personally did before moving to Method 2:

```
class Queue:
  def __init__(self, client: discord.Client, vc: discord.VoiceClient, ctx):
      self._client = client
      self._queue: List[Song] = list()
      self._vc = vc
      self._ctx = ctx

  def _addSong(self, song: Song):
    self._queue.append(song)
    if len(self._queue) == 1:
         self.loopedTask = 
          self._client.loop.create_task(self.create_loop_task())

  def addSongs(self, songs: List[Song]):
      for song in songs:
          if len(self._queue) == 1:
              self.next = song
          self._addSong(song)

  def deleteSong(self, index):
      self._queue.pop(index - 1)
```

NOTE: It's not my full code, the code I've done was a bit more complex than this but it's a general idea about how it's supposed to work.

### **Method 2**

Personally what I did is using Linked lists ( Nodes ) to represent my queue.
In python ( and other languages in general ) there's a method called Queue, which allows people to queue, dequeue and see their first data in a very specific way called FIFO ( First In First Out ), you can see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-queue-using-doubly-linked-list/) for further explanation about the Queue method.
What I find unique in this method is the fact that everything is linked together, meaning it's easier to navigate your current song, from there you can just get the next data in one line, without checking if there is a song or not because this method does it for you.
I also suggest learning about [nodes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_nodes.htm) before doing this method because of the complexity it has over the first method.

A few things I suggest when working with a music bot in general:

- Use a library called [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp), it's a fork of the original youtube-dl but more efficient in terms of finding and extracting songs from youtube
- Use FFMPEG as it's the easiest to control your songs with ( at least from what I saw online )
- When using Queues and stuff like that, use different files so you can have order in your head ( my personal order is Queue related stuff in one file and the class to extract data in another ). Because you can call them directly from your functions it shouldn't be a problem to just do it.
- Here are my options for YTDL in case you need them:

> YTDL_OPS = {
> 'format': 'bestaudio/best',
> 'extractaudio': True,
> 'audioformat': 'mp3',
> 'restrictfilenames': True,
> 'nocheckcertificate': True,
> 'ignoreerrors': False,
> 'logtostderr': False,
> 'quiet': True,
> 'no_warnings': True,
> 'default_search': 'auto',
> 'source_address': '0.0.0.0',
> 'playlistend': 25
> }